# Reading input input into a char pointer with scanf

Tags: c, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

What I want to do here is, I want to read input from a user with scanf into a char pointer and dynamically allocate memory as more input is read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr, temp;
    int i, ind = 0;

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);

    while (scanf(" %[^\n]c", &temp) != EOF)
    {
        ptr[ind] = temp;
        ind++;
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(char) * (ind + 1));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%c", *(ptr + i));

    return 0;
}
```

My code is like this, however it either throws a segmentation error (when the number of character in one line is more than 8) or does not even print any characters. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `2 * sizeof(char)` doesn't do exactly what you think, you only allocate memory for **2** characters.

Comment: @alex01011: That is what they think. They start with two characters and use `realloc` to get more as characters are read.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well `scanf()` is the wrong function to use then:)

Comment: In that form at least

Comment: This is what the `m` flag to scanf is for:  `scanf("% m[^\n]", &ptr);`

Comment: @ChrisDodd: `m` is not a standard C modifier.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: No but it is part of the POSIX standard, so is available everywhere that matters.

Comment: Well -- almost. Compilers are free to not implement it (and many don't). The `m` (originally `a`) is hit or miss at best. The `-std=gnuXX` will support it, but `-std=cXX` doesn't. (where `XX` is just a generic version) Better just to create `temp` as an , e.g. `1024` char array and read with `fgets()` trimming the newline and getting the length with `strcspn()` and then allocate  `length + 1` chars for `ptr` and `memcpy()` `temp` to `ptr` copying `length + 1` chars (or just use `strcpy()`)

Comment: If you want to store each of the user inputs and then be able to access each, your use of a single *pointer-to* `char` isn't what you want to use for storage. (you can, but you would have to keep a separate collection of the start-index and length of each input so you could separate the inputs within the single block of memory pointed to by `ptr`). If you have a max number of inputs, you can create an *array-of-pointers-to* `char`, if not you can use a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char` (e.g. `char **ptr;`) and allocate/reallocate pointers as needed, and allocate for each line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `-std=c99` doesn't enter into it (see https://godbolt.org/z/n6G4frsW9), as it is part of the library, not the C compiler, and if your standard library is POSIX compliant it will support it regardless of what the compiler says (or does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Eric's answer, your code could be better without `scanf()`. Here is a `getchar()` solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c = 0; /* int so it can hold the EOF value */
    size_t ind = 0, i = 0;
    char *buff = NULL, *tmp = NULL;

    buff = malloc(2); /* sizeof char is 1 */

    if (buff == NULL) /* malloc failed */
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        c = getchar();

        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }

        buff[ind++] = (char)c; /* maybe check for overflow here, for non ascii characters */

        /* can use ctype functions or just manually compare with CHAR_MIN and CHAR_MAX */

        tmp = realloc(buff, ind + 2);

        if (tmp == NULL) /* reallloc failed */
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        buff = tmp;
    }

    /* --------- NULL terminate if you are looking for a string  */

    /* buff[ind] = 0;                                            */

    /* --------------------------------------------------------- */

    for (; i < ind; i++)
    {
        putchar(*(buff + i));
    }

    free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like add that multiple `realloc()` calls, isn't really a sufficient practice. The better approach, would be initially allocate an *X* amount of memory with `malloc()` and if you need more, then use `realloc()` with an appropriate size.

Comment: Assigning the result of `realloc` to the same pointer as the input parameter is wrong.  There are many people more knowledgeable than I, who would advise to not use `realloc` at all; instead call `malloc`, test whether it was successful, free the one you are using, and then overwrite it with the new value returned by the most recent `malloc`

Comment: `buff = realloc(buff, ind + 2);` when (not if) `realloc()` fails you overwrite the address held by `buff` with `NULL` losing your original pointer address creating a memory leak. Always `realloc()` using a temp pointer, e.g. `void *tmp =  realloc(buff, ind + 2); if (!tmp) { perror ("realloc-buff"); /* handle error */ } buff = tmp;`

Comment: I used realloc because the size of the input was not known, and I was told to use it. But your solution works like charm. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @GeorgeMiddletown What they pointed is correct. I updated the answer. Thanks gents!

Answer (score 3):

`scanf(" %[^\n]c", &temp)` does not read a character that is not a new-line (`'\n'`). The `[` is a conversion specifier by itself, and `c` does not go with it.

`%[^\n]` says to read any number of characters until a new-line is seen. The `c` is not part of the conversion, and its presence causes a matching failure in `scanf`.

To read one character that is not a new-line character, use `%1[^\n]`, as in `scanf(" %1[^\n]", &temp);`

Another solutions are:

- Use `%c` in the scanf. Afterward, test the character and ignore it if it is a new-line character.
- Change the code to use `getchar` instead of `scanf`.

Avoid testing with `scanf(...) != EOF`. `scanf` returns `EOF` only if an input failure occurs before the first conversion has completed. Otherwise, it returns the number of input items assigned. This may work in simple uses of `scanf` with only one item to assign. However, in general, you want to at least test whether `scanf` assigned the desired number of items, `scanf(...) == 1`. Even better would be to save the return value and handle the multiple possible returns: `EOF`, a number less than the desired number of items, or the desired number of items.